# Schedule to stop and start instance on Google Cloud Platform - Cloud Scheduler it's the Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have the following need. I would like every day at 5:00 am to restart my instance, so I read the best way to automate it would be using Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Function, but I am not aware of these two GCP features.

I created two schedules in the Cloud Scheduler where my VM instance **STOP** at 5:00 am and another one that **START** at 5:10 am, but I don't know how to proceed in Cloud Function to end my process.

Could someone help me with this? hug to everyone!

See how are my project error log when trying to implement

**ERROR**

```
{ "jobName": "projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/jobs/Stop", "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "status": "INTERNAL", "url": "https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/power/stop?zone=us-central1-a&instance=my-instance", "targetType": "HTTP" }

###############

    {
insertId: "1klx7n3g18eq5zs"
jsonPayload: {
jobName: "projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/jobs/Stop"
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
status: "INTERNAL"
url: "https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/power/stop?zone=us-central1-a&instance=my-instance"
targetType: "HTTP"
}
httpRequest: {
status: 500
}
resource: {
type: "cloud_scheduler_job"
labels: {
location: "us-central1"
project_id: "my-project"
job_id: "Stop"
}
}
timestamp: "2020-08-07T08:00:06.896367090Z"
severity: "ERROR"
logName: "projects/my-project/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
receiveTimestamp: "2020-08-07T08:00:06.896367090Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case on my project, and I use this python function in order to start and stop a vm, my function can handle the paths `start` and `stop`

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import os
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def power(path=None):
    #this libraries are mandatory to reach compute engine api
    from googleapiclient import discovery
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


    #the function will take the service account of your function
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

    #this line is to specify the api that we gonna use, in this case compute engine    
    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
    logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    # Project ID for this request.
    project = yourprojectID  # Update placeholder value.
    zone = request.args.get('zone', None)
    instance = request.args.get('instance', None)

    #call the method to start or stop the instance
    if (request.path == "/stop"):
        req = service.instances().stop(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)

    elif (request.path == "/start"):
        req = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
    else:
        abort(418)
    #execute the command
    response = req.execute()

    print(response)
    return ("OK")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

requirements.txt file

```
google-api-python-client
oauth2client
flask
```

Scheduler config

1. [Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#console-console) with [functions.invoker permission](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#console-console) within your function
2. [Create new Cloud scheduler job](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating)
3. Specify the frequency in cron format.
4. Specify HTTP as the target type.
5. Add the URL of your cloud function and method as always.
6. Select the token OIDC from the Auth header dropdown
7. Add the service account email in the Service account text box.
8. In `audience field` you must only need to write the URL of the function without any additional parameter

On cloud scheduler, I hit my function by using these URLs

`https://us-central1-yourprojectID.cloudfunctions.net/power/stop?zone=us-central1-a&instance=instance-1`

`https://us-central1-yourprojectID.cloudfunctions.net/power/stop?zone=us-central1-a&instance=instance-1`

and I used this audience

`https://us-central1-yourprojectID.cloudfunctions.net/power`

please replace `yourprojectID` in the code and in the URLs

`us-central1` is the region where my function is located, `power` is the name of my function, `us-central1-a` is the zone where my instance is located and `instance-1` is the name of my instance

**update for java**

Cloud functions supports java11 and maven but this is on beta

first you need this dependencies, please add the following lines to your pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-compute</artifactId>
      <version>beta-rev20200629-1.30.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.30.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Cloud function to START a VM

```
package com.example;

import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.compute.Compute;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.Operation;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Example implements HttpFunction {
  @Override
  public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws Exception, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    
    
    // Project ID for this request.
    String project = "my-project"; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The name of the zone for this request.
    String zone = "my-zone"; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // Name of the instance resource to start.
    String instance = "my-instance"; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    Compute computeService = createComputeService();

    // you can change the method start to stop 
    Compute.Instances.Start request = computeService.instances().start(project, zone, instance);
    
    Operation xresponse = xrequest.execute();

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    System.out.println(xresponse);

    BufferedWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write("Done");


  }

  public static Compute createComputeService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential =
          credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }

    return new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-ComputeSample/0.1")
        .build();
  }

}
```

For more information you can check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances/start#python) in this document are some examples in different programming languages

Comment: JAHernández thanks for the tip, I will analyze your response, would anyone have something in java?

Comment: in this document you can find how to call app engine api by using java  

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances/start#java

Comment: @JAHernández thank you quickly worked congratulations, I will try to implement any doubts back.

Comment: @JAHernández I updated my question with log and files

Comment: @Jarciano, as is indicated in your error log, it is necessary to rename the variables `request` &  `response` in `service`, please check the updated code in my answer, now this variables are called `xrequest` & `xresponse`

Comment: @JAHernández i updated my question log after implementing the corrections suggested by you

Comment: @Jarciano please use the full code, that I posted in the answer I tested it on my project and is working without issues

Comment: @JAHernández i managed to get the project deployed, but I updated the error log the moment I tried to run the process on the Cloud Scheduler this is giving PERMISSION_DENIED error. where do we need to release?

Comment: @Jarciano in this answer I posted how to authenticate your scheduler request, the scheduler part is at the end of the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62285013/11529321

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218939/discussion-between-jarciano-and-j-a-hernandez).

Comment: @JAHernández Could you share images of how this is your setup? because I believe I'm missing a small detail.

Comment: @Jarciano Target: ` HTTP` , URL:`https://us-central1-projectID.cloudfunctions.net/poweron`,HTTP method:`get` ,Auth header: `Add OIDC token`, Service account:`service@projectID.iam.gserviceaccount.com `, Audiencie:`https://us-central1-projectID.cloudfunctions.net/poweron`, in `audience field` you must only need to write the url of the function without any additional parameter

Comment: @JAHernández I updated with an image for you to see the error I get.

Comment: @Jarciano you need to put Auth header:  `OIDC token`, I'm in the chat

Comment: @JAHernández add a chat image from the log when trying to run

Comment: @JAHernández See the function log record, do I have to do any commands on my VM to accept the call of stop and start? https://imgur.com/q05mKZP

Comment: Hello, @JAHernández

I updated my question, because the error is now showing something different I believe it is some detail of the server accepting the function call

Comment: @Jarciano, can you share the execution log of the cloud function?

Comment: @JAHernández Would these logs be? https://imgur.com/pjjwzpe | https://imgur.com/oZhmbXR

Comment: @Jarciano i recommend you open a support case, as I mentioned this is working fine on my productive project and support has more visibility about what is crashing.

https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers